# In Angular2+ is there any way to extends on inherit const into another const?

Tags: angular

I trying to inherit or extend const into another const

Parent.ts

```
export const Vehicle = {
  'Name': 'Honda',
  'NoOfWheels': '4'
}
```

Child.ts

```
import { Vehicle } from './Parent';
export const HondaVehicle = {
    'VehicleName': 'Honda City',
    'Color': 'Red',
    'EngineCC': '2100cc',
}
```

So I am expecting output

```
{
      'Name': 'Honda',
      'NoOfWheels': '4',
      'VehicleName': 'Honda City',
      'Color': 'Red',
      'EngineCC': '2100cc',
}
```

So kind help me.

Comment: The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is made for that !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As trichetriche said you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
import { Vehicle } from './Parent';
export const HondaVehicle = {
   'VehicleName': 'Honda City',
   'Color': 'Red',
   'EngineCC': '2100cc',
    ...Vehicle
}
```

Alternatively you can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
import { Vehicle } from './Parent';
export const HondaVehicle = Object.assign({
   'VehicleName': 'Honda City',
   'Color': 'Red',
   'EngineCC': '2100cc',
}, Vehicle)
```

This is not exclusive to Angular by the way, it's a javascript thing.